# Callback for camera shutter open event

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been working around in UIImagePickerController and am struck with a problem where I need to get the precise moment when the camera shutter opens in UIImagePickerController when the source type is set to camera (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera).

I have done some googling around and have realized that no one had such strange requirement!

I looked around the docs of UIImagePickerController and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate hoping to get some delegate method / callback indicating the camera shutter open event, but did not find any.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help,

Raj Pawan

Comment: can you tell us more about why you think you need to know this and what are you trying to accomplish?  you could presumably figure this out by calling UIGetScreenImage and "looking" for the shutter...

Comment: I am trying out a sample app to get the screen image by using takePicture and private api UIGetScreenImage, later I found out that UIGetScreenImage gives the shutter image too! Thats quite obvious if you are using a private API though. So I was wondering if I could trigger UIGetScreenImage a little late after the shutter is retracted, for this to accomplish I need some callback / delegate method which informs that the shutter is open.

I couldnt quite get the meaning of "UIGetScreenImage and "looking" for the shutter... –", how do I differentiate the shutter image from other camera images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to observe for a private notification, just as discussed in this thread:
[Detecting when camera's iris is open on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone/1581317).

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to:

```
AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification
```

This is when the iris open animation begins.  If you add a cameraOverlayView during this time, it will be properly covered up by the iris.  It is posted at the same time as that PL… private notification.  This is a documented approach that does not risk app rejection.

Comment: Yes, but my question was asked when AV framework did not exist and our deployment target was as low as iOS 3.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion (didn't try it myself but don't see why it wouldn't work) :

- Subclass the `UIImagePickerController` class into your own class, and override the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear : those methods will be triggered when the UIImagePickerController is about to appear or does appear (if you trigger its display properly using `presentModalController` for instance) .

```
    @interface MyUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController {
    }
    @end
```

```
@implementation MyUIImagePickerController
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"the picker is about to appear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"the picker did appear");
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
@end
```

Comment: @yonel, It does not work. viewDidAppear is called as soon as the image picker controller's view is displayed with the camera shutter closed.

Comment: hum, I didn't think the accuracy you were expecting was such "extreme" :) Maybe can you tell us why you need to get such accuracy in the timing of the opening of the camera shutter ? Maybe this would give ideas to "work around" this :/

Comment: I did some more googling with different key words (iris instead of shutter) and stumbled upon this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone/1581317. It solves all my problem. I am keeping my fingers crossed, hope that apple wont reject it.

Comment: Apple was fine with us using this notification. Probably because we are just registering for a notification and we arent calling any private API.