# Hide/Show iPhone Camera Iris/Shutter animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am not able to Hide the iphone Camera shutter opening animation for my app.
I am using UIImagePickerController to access iphone camera and using my own overlay controllers.
Is there a way to remove the initial shutter(also known as Iris) animation as the camera starts.
Thank You

[EDIT]

For those who wants to know the way to change the camera iris animation.

The below function is called before the camera iris animation starts.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Here is were I make the camera preview fit the entire screen. 
    // This might violate the "don't change the view hierarchy"-rule. 
    // So I am not sure if it is valid for App Store commitment.
    // However, the NSLogs are used to
    // figure out which subview is the actual Camera Preview which turns out 
    // to be the PLPreviewView. (uncomment to se the printouts).
    // Change it's size to fit the entire screen (and scale it accordingly
    // to avoid distorted image

    NSLog(@"WillShowViewController called...");

    NSLog(@"VC:view:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[viewController view] subviews]);

    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews]);

    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:PLPreviewView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews]);
    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:PLCropOverLay:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 1] subviews]);
    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:UIImageView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 2] subviews]);

}
```

In the above function you can go through each layer by using the normal NSMuatableArray syntax like objectAtIndex

hope this might help you.

Regards,

Ankur

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question too. Been searching and haven't seen anything. Let us know if you figure this out!

Comment: Yeah I found the solution by playing around with the view hierarchy of the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: seems the answers below can't get through App approval

Comment: Can you please post your code in your question itself as I am facing same issue and need to hide that animation of shutter.

Comment: I have edited the question with the solution of how to access the view hierarchy of the camera animation.

Comment: For information, some applications does not show this shutter/iris, and also starts immediately (without waiting for the expected shutter animation duration). Also ZBar Lib don't show the shutter animation. So I think we can find a better solution.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to access the camera api for iPhone which I found for my previous application. It is using AVCaptureSession. Checkout the sample on developer.apple.com called SquareCam. It demonstrates how to directly access the Camera API without showing the shutter animation.

Answer (score 5):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone/1674660#1674660) as a starting point, I've finally solved this problem:

**NOTE: This is obviously not 3.3.1-compliant.**

1. Listen for the `UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification` on your `UIImagePickerController`, and the `PLCameraViewIrisAnimationDidEndNotification` globally.
2. Traverse the view hierarchy (starting at the main `UIWindow`) looking for the `PLCameraView`. Save the index of the view against the main `UIWindow`, as you'll need it later.
3. Remove the `PLCameraView` from its `superView`. If desired, insert your own view at global index 0.
4. When the iris animation is finished, remove your view and re-add the `PLCameraView` at its original index.

Answer (score 1):

Came across a similar: I wanted to have the shutter appear when I take the picture triggered by a button in a self.cameraOverlayView of a UIImagePickerController. Arrived to this page, did some extra research and came to this solution.

**Synopsis:**

```
@interface MyController : UIImagePickerController
...    
- (id) init {
...
    self.cameraOverlayView = _my_overlay_;
    self.showsCameraControls = NO;
...
}
... 
- (void) onMyShutterButton {
    [self takePicture]; 
        // You want the shutter animation to happen now.
        // .. but it does not.
}
```

**Solution:**

```
// Some constants for the iris view and selector
NSString* kIrisViewClassName = @"PLCameraIrisAnimationView";
SEL kIrisSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"animateIrisOpen");

@implementation MyController {
...
    UIView* iris_;
}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Find the iris view in the siblings of your overlay view
    for (UIView* view in self.cameraOverlayView.superview.subviews) {
        if ([kIrisViewClassName isEqualToString:[[view class] description]]) {
            // It will be hidden by 'self.showsCameraControls = NO'.
            view.hidden = false;   
            // Extra precautions - as this is undocumented.  
            if ([view respondsToSelector:kIrisSelector]) {
                iris_ = view;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
- (void) animateIrisOpen {
    if (iris_) {
        [iris_ performSelector:kIrisSelector];
    }
}
...
- (void) onMyShutterButton {
    [self takePicture]; 
    [self animateIrisOpen];   // Voila - the shutter happens
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've messed around with this a bit, but sending various combinations of the view lifecycle methods to the image picker. (viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc.)  But I don't remember which ones ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying getting back so late. I found out the solution for that well I played around with the view hierarchy of the cameraView and added my own layer at the top of everything. The animation took place there and once the shutter was open the top most layer was removed. If someone need any further help with the code please let me know, I will provide with the exact steps and syntax.

-Ankur

Comment: Can you please post your code in your question itself as I am facing same issue and need to hide that animation of shutter.

Answer (score 0):

The below function is called before the camera iris animation starts.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Here is were I make the camera preview fit the entire screen. 
    // This might violate the "don't change the view hierarchy"-rule. 
    // So I am not sure if it is valid for App Store commitment.
    // However, the NSLogs are used to
    // figure out which subview is the actual Camera Preview which turns out 
    // to be the PLPreviewView. (uncomment to se the printouts).
    // Change it's size to fit the entire screen (and scale it accordingly
    // to avoid distorted image

    NSLog(@"WillShowViewController called...");

    NSLog(@"VC:view:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[viewController view] subviews]);

    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews]);

    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:PLPreviewView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews]);
    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:PLCropOverLay:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 1] subviews]);
    NSLog(@"VC:view:PLCameraView:UIImageView:subviews\n %@\n\n", [[[[[[viewController view] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 2] subviews]);

}
```

In the above function you can go through each layer by using the normal NSMuatableArray syntax like objectAtIndex

hope this might help you.

Regards,

Ankur

Comment: Thank you Harsh for formatting the code. I didn't know the shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

joshwa's answer completely hides the entire camera view for the duration of the iris animation.  For my purposes, I needed the camera view visible, just without the iris animation.  I was able to accomplish this with a little tweaking of his method.  As others have noted, this may or may not be allowed on the app store since we're messing with the view hierarchy as well as listening for undocumented notifications.

3 ivars are needed:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
UIView *plCameraIrisAnimationView;  // view that animates the opening/closing of the iris
UIImageView *cameraIrisImageView;  // static image of the closed iris
```

Hide the closed iris image and remove the animation view.  I tried simply hiding the animation view as well, but the animation was still visible:

```
- (void)receivedNavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIView *view = imagePickerController.view;
    [plCameraIrisAnimationView release];
    plCameraIrisAnimationView = nil;
    cameraIrisImageView = nil;
    while (view.subviews.count && (view = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:0])) {
        if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLCameraView"]) {
            for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
                if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                    cameraIrisImageView = (UIImageView *)subview;
                }
                else if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLCropOverlay"]) {
                    for (UIView *subsubview in subview.subviews) {
                        if ([[[subsubview class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLCameraIrisAnimationView"]) {
                            plCameraIrisAnimationView = [subsubview retain];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cameraIrisImageView.hidden = YES;
    [plCameraIrisAnimationView removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedPLCameraViewIrisAnimationDidEndNotification:) name:@"PLCameraViewIrisAnimationDidEndNotification" object:nil];
}
```

When the animation is over, unhide the iris image and re-add the animation view:

```
- (void)receivedPLCameraViewIrisAnimationDidEndNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    cameraIrisImageView.hidden = NO;

    UIView *view = imagePickerController.view;
    while (view.subviews.count && (view = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:0])) {
        if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLCameraView"]) {
            for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
                if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLCropOverlay"]) {
                    [subview insertSubview:plCameraIrisAnimationView atIndex:1];
                    [plCameraIrisAnimationView release];
                    plCameraIrisAnimationView = nil;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PLCameraViewIrisAnimationDidEndNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes, it does not work on iOS5, I tried replacing that with AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification and AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunningNotification, but it work on iOS5 and not with the same behaviour on iOS 4

Answer (score 0):

To expound on Catalin's answer, (which was great btw), I found if you change the method "animateIrisOpen" slightly, the presentation is a fraction better... but noticeable.

```
- (void) animateIrisOpen {
    if (iris_) {
        iris_.hidden = NO;
        [iris_ performSelector:kIrisSelector];
    }
}
```