# Disable image picker default animation in iphone

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi 
I have the following code which pulls up the camera and add an overlay on the camera's view. Before the camera shows up, there is an animation. Is there a way that can remove the animation and jumps to the overlay view right away?

```
//create an overlay view instance
    OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

    //create a new image picker instance
    UIImagePickerController *picker = 
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    //set source to video!
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    //[picker startVideoCapture];

    //picker. = 1;
    //hide all controls
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    //make the video preview full size
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    picker.cameraViewTransform =
    CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform,
                           CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,
                           CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
    //set our custom overlay view
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    //show picker
    //[self.view insertSubview:picker.view atIndex:0];  
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];   
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:overlay];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

[Hide/Show iPhone Camera Iris/Shutter animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation)

Comment: I couldn't find PLCameraView in the view hierachy. here is the method I used.  #import "MyImagePicker.h"
@implementation MyImagePicker
- (void) notificationCallback:(NSNotification *) notification {
 if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification"]) {
 //NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews);
 //UIView *view1 = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
  //[view1 removeFromSuperview];
  for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
   NSLog(@"%@",view);
   
  }
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
}