# UIImagePickerViewController - Disable Iris Animation ( needs Apple-approved codes )

Tags: ios4

How to disable Iris Animation ( needs Apple-approved codes ) of UIImagePickerViewController ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide/Show iPhone Camera Iris/Shutter animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible as all the methods allowing you to do that are private. You'll have to roll out your own implementation using AV framework or take a look at https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/ that has a camera implementation already.