# iOS:How to open camera with animation effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, camera

I want to open camera with animation effect, so that it should appear that camera is opening in the parent screen only.
I am using camera overlay screen and on click event of button in parent screen,camera overlay screen is opening,in camera overlay screen there is a cancel button to close the camera,so while closing the camera again I need to show the animation effect that it should appear that now camera is closed in the same parent scree. 
I have tried kCATransitionMoveIn but not fully satisfied,if any once has better solution please help me.

```
CATransition * contentAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    contentAnimation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    contentAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    contentAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    contentAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:contentAnimation forKey:kCATransition];
    //self.view.hidden = YES;
    [CATransaction commit];
    // Show the scanner overlay
    [self presentModalViewController:overlayController.parentPicker animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: May be below URL help you..

[See this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and I have taken the ZBar SDK example as a reference and this [link1](http://jonathanhui.com/ios-camera-image) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation) also helped me.

Answer (score 5):

This could be somewhat tidious but try out downloading [ZBar SDK](http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/zbar/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg) which is .dmg file. and double click it. You will find Examples Folder. In that you will find 4 apps. Try out that app in Device only. You will find amazing CAMERA open with animation effect.