# HIde shutter animation UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to hide animation that shows shutter opening while presenting UIImagePickerController to take picture. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation) for the same which contains the accepted but I was unable to replicate that functionality in my controller.

I gave overlayView as self.view and when I hide PLCameraView it shows blank white portion and than I am able to take picture. Is there any way to remove that white portion ?

IF needed I can post my full sourcecode project...

Can some body please highlight how to do this ?

**Edit:**

What I want to do is based on certain event and conditions I want to place image taken from camera or default image in db. And picture taking doesn't involve user interaction so I put NSTimer and take snapshot with the help of `takePicture` method.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing about with the view hierarchy of UIImagePickerController (which you are  forcefully warned against in the docs) you should probably use AVCaptureSession and create your own ImagePicker to capture raw images from the video feed.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamCaptureManager_m.html for hints.

Comment: link went down, changed to more detailed Apple image capture source