# UIImagePickerController: invoke takePicture without shuttering animation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm invoking UIImagePickerController's method takePicture method to programmatically pictures with the iPhone

However I would like to disable the shuttering animation, and just leave the screen as it is, when the picture is taken (and disabling the sound as well).

**UPDATE**
I'm now using AVFoundation APIs to get the image, but the content of the camera is not displayed anymore on the screen. Should I initialize a UIImagePickerController just to display the content of the camera on the screen ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this sample: It uses AVCaptureSession and an ImagePicker to capture images from the video. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamCaptureManager_m.html

Also this one: https://github.com/jj0b/AROverlayExample

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController has some options, but not a lot.  [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138502/hide-show-iphone-camera-iris-shutter-animation) has some tacky but probably effective ideas for disabling it.

For complete control, you need to use the AVFoundation APIs.  Here is a capture example:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

Answer (score -1):

I think this useful for 3.0

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  
{  

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"])
    {
        UIImage *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


        UIImage * cameraimage= [self scaleAndRotateImage:selectedImage];

        CGRect rect =CGRectMake(0, 0,640,875);        
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([selectedImage CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
        CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
        self.captureimage.image=cameraimage;

        NSLog(@"selectedimage width:%f ht:%f",img.size.width,img.size.height);
    }
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```