# Detect when camera is ready to use

Tags: iphone

I'm making an app where you have an overlay over your camera, but I can't seem to be able to detect when the camera is capturing image. I don't want to show my overlay until the gray cameras shutters open and the actual captured footage is shown. It seems that the period of time it takes varies depending on if you recently used it and what not.

Is there any way to detect when this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when camera's iris is open on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone/1674660#1674660)

Discussion continues whether this may be a reason for your app being rejected, as it is using undocumented functionality. However you're not actually calling a private API and if you (as the linked answer suggests) take precautions to keep your app working even if the notification should be subject to change in a future release of iOS, you should be good to go. It appears like some popular apps available on the appstore make use of this too.