# IPhone Camera Shutter issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

basically I am trying to use the camera function but want to be able to upload a picture once the camera button is pressed without touching the use button.

Therefore the delegate camera method never gets called. I am however trying to capture the screen using the following method to get the image:

UIGetScreenImage()

This seems unorthodox but does the trick. My issue comes with the fact that sometimes, I get the shutter image. Is there delegate method called when the shutter animation is complete?

If so, any help is more than welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: There is a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570419/detecting-when-cameras-iris-is-open-on-iphone

Comment: There is an answer here as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932924/iphone-grab-picture-from-camera-when-takepicture-method-called

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932924/iphone-grab-picture-from-camera-when-takepicture-method-called

Answer (score 0):

Use stillCamera from Brad Larson https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage