# Iphone Grab picture from camera when takepicture method called

Tags: objective-c, ios4, camera, uipickerviewcontroller

Hello all I wanted to know if it is possible to get the UIIMAGE reference from the iphone camera after I press the takepicture button. I don't want to have to press on the use button for the delegate method to be called before I can access the image.

One way of doing that is by copying whatever is on the screen at that time but the problem is that I have a overlayed view so am getting the image with the frame.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: The solution is to set camera overlay to No and then the delegate will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if we call the showcameracontrols = no , the delegate method for grabbing the image gets called as soon as the picture is called. If not,then the delegate method is called when the use button is pressed. T